# objdump with nodejs script that throws segmentation error

Tags: javascript, node.js, segmentation-fault, objdump

I have nodejs script that throws
`Error: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)`

After I included

```
var SegfaultHandler = require('segfault-handler');

    SegfaultHandler.registerHandler("crash.log"); // With no argument, SegfaultHandler will generate a generic log file name
```

I got this stack trace:

```
PID 2645 received SIGSEGV for address: 0x0
0   segfault-handler.node               0x00000001034ae1c8 _ZL16segfault_handleriP9__siginfoPv + 280
1   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff9364b52a _sigtramp + 26
2   ???                                 0x0000000000000010 0x0 + 16
3   node                                0x000000010067bbdc _ZN2v88internal23Runtime_GetFrameDetailsEiPPNS0_6ObjectEPNS0_7IsolateE + 2364
4   ???                                 0x00000a107710961b 0x0 + 11065833330203
5   ???                                 0x00000a107795c134 0x0 + 11065842057524
```

The next step is to use `objdump -dS`.
The question is how to use objdump?

Comment: hey, were you able to figure it out? I am trying to do the same as you but I'm quite lost

Comment: Yeah. I didnt have complete json or smth like that. File was corrupted

Comment: Could you please explain how you used objdump with your node app? I have tried generating a binary but I haven't been successful

Comment: I used it to write big JSON files to xxx.json 
It was long time ago, I have no code no more.